# How to call controller function without declared in Route in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

i want to call the controller => function without specifying in route in Laravel 5.1.

such as controller / function

Example: admin/delete

so i want to call the above controller's function without specifying in routes is their any way to do that?
Also, if it is possible then how to pass parameters to that function?

Comment: I think you are trying to emulate `Code Igniter` structure, where controllers automatically responds to url with `/controller/function` structure. NO, you can not do it in Laravel. The most accurate structure is @kota's answer

Comment: okay, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [RESTful Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

So in your route file you only have:

```
Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');
```

and in your controller:

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

    public function show($adminId)
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy($adminId)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: i just don't want to use route to call a controller function, same as we do in cakephp and codeigniter.

Comment: I think you have to add some line to routes.php. :(